# Linq to SQL сложить дату и время

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
from Manager in db.Manager
join Manager_History in db.Manager_History on new { id = (int)
    ((from Manager_History0 in db.Manager_History
    where
      Manager_History0.idmanager == Manager.id
    orderby
      Manager_History0.id descending
    select new {
      Manager_History0.id
    }).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().id) } equals new { id = Manager_History.id } into Manager_History_join
from Manager_History in Manager_History_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
  (DateTime)(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Double)Manager_History.date_end) + " " + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Double)Manager_History.time_end)) >= SqlFunctions.GetDate() || // Проблема вот здесь с приведением типов и тд...
  (String)Manager_History.date_end == "1900-01-01"
orderby
  Manager_History.sip
select new {
  sip = (int?)Manager_History.sip,
  Проект = Manager.Projects.Project_name,
  Менеджер = (Manager.Userser.Users.firstname.TrimEnd() + " " + Manager.Userser.Users.name.TrimEnd()),
  date_start = (DateTime?)Manager_History.date_start,
  time_start = Manager_History.time_start,
  date_end = (DateTime?)Manager_History.date_end,
  time_end = Manager_History.time_end
}
```

Нужно сложить дату и время, и сравнить с текущей датой и временем. Не могу довести преобразование...

Ошибка  CS0030  Не удается преобразовать тип "System.DateTime?" в "double"  CRM_1CallCenterWPF

```
Manager_History.date_end.Value.Add(Manager_History.time_end.Value) >= SqlFunctions.GetDate() ||
```

Ошибка:
System.NotSupportedException: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Add(System.TimeSpan)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."
Или я что то не так делаю?!

Comment: Хоть с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34346061/5045688):

```
where DbFunctions.AddMilliseconds(Manager_History.date_end, DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(Manager_History.time_end, TimeSpan.Zero))
    >= SqlFunctions.GetDate()
|| Manager_History.date_end == new DateTime(1900, 01, 01)
```

Для удобочитаемости можно ввести локальную переменную с помощью `let`:

```
let totalMilliseconds = DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(Manager_History.time_end, TimeSpan.Zero)

where DbFunctions.AddMilliseconds(Manager_History.date_end, totalMilliseconds)
```

Ещё можно вместо конструктора `DateTime` использовать метод `Parse`, если дата именно в виде строки задана. Для этого вызовем его до linq-запроса:

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01");


...
|| Manager_History.date_end == dt
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял (а я мог неверно понять, т.к. предоставлено недостаточно информации), то:

Подробнее об ошибке [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0030).
Очевидно, вы пытаетесь преобразовать double в DateTime в этом участке кода:

```
    ...where
        (DateTime)(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Double)Manager_History.date_end)
```

Это так не сработает.

Если в вашей БД даты хранятся в формате строки, то попробуйте распарсить их с помощью:

```
DateTime.Parse(yourString);
```

А далее, можете сложить даты, любым удобным вам способом.

Надеюсь, поможет.

P.S. Кстати, У вас слишком громоздкий запрос. Советую разбить его на несколько подзапросов, что бы улучшить читабельность кода и облегчить отладку.

UPD 1. 
По вашему вопросу о том, как разбить код:
Имелось в виду, что полезно для отладки и читабельности писать по одному селекту в переменную.
Например:

```
var x = from item in myEnumerable 
where item.Condition1 
select item;

var y = from item in x
where item.Condition2 == false
select item;

var z = y.FirstOrDefault();
```

и т.д.

А еще задайтесь вопросом, что делают конструкции `XXX.Take(1).FirstOrDefault().id` в вашем коде.

Comment: В базе Дата - Date Время - Time(7). В моделе Дата - DateTime Время - TimeSpan. Мне нужно к дате прибавить время и сравнить с текущей.

Comment: А на примере моего запроса можете показать как вы разбиваете запрос? А то я что то не могу понять о чём вы.

Comment: Вы можете к дате прибавить время через `DateTime.Add().`
[Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.add(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @LaNC1LoT - странно, что вы отметили это сообщение. Ведь здесь нет ответа на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Отметил за помощь в нахождении другой ошибки)) И за пример разбития на под запросы.